# Not the expected output file is generated

Tags: bash, sorting, sed, cut

I am currently trying to filter a lexicon which is structured as such:

snippet of the Lexicon_a:

```
<oov> <oov>
A  AH0
A  EY1
A''S    EY1 Z
A'BODY  EY1 B AA2 D IY0
A'COURT EY1 K AO2 R T
A'D EY1 D
A'GHA   EY1 G AH0
A'GOIN  EY1 G OY1 N
A'LL    EY1 L
A'M EY1 M
A'MIGHTY    EY1 M AY1 T IY0
A'MIGHTY'S  EY1 M AY1 T IY0 Z
A'MOST  EY1 M OW2 S T
A'N'T   EY1 AH0 N T
A'PENNY EY1 P EH2 N IY0
A'READY EY1 R IY1 D IY0
A'RIGHT EY1 R AY2 T
A'RONY  EY1 R OW1 N IY0
A'S  EY1 Z
A'TER   EY1 T ER0
A'TERNOON   EY1 T ER0 N UW1 N
A'TERWARDS  EY1 T ER0 W ER0 D Z
A'THEGITHER EY1 DH AH0 JH IH1 DH ER0
A'THING EY1 DH IH0 NG
A'TIM   EY1 T IH2 M
A'VE    AH0 V
AA  AA1
```

To a file with non-silence phone. So basically a file with all the phonemes listed in a files. the phonemes must only appear ones in the file.

I tried something like this

```
cut -f 2- lexicon.txt | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort -u > nonsilence_phones.txt
```

But this seem to give a bit messed up output. A combination of words and phoenemes. how do I only extract the phonemes, and make only appear ones. 
Messed up output:

```
<oov>
A
A'S
AA1
AA2
AH0
AO2
AY1
AY2
B
D
DH
EH2
ER0
EY1
G
IH0
IH1
IH2
IY0
IY1
JH
K
L
M
N
NG
OW1
OW2
OY1
P
R
S
T
UW1
V
W
Z
```

The lexicon entries as listed as such

```
word '\t' phonemes
```

I tried 
    cut -d ' ' -f 2- lexicon.txt | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort -u > nonsilence_phones.txt

On a different lexicon_b.txt

```
<oov> <oov>
A AH
AND AH N D
APOSTROPHE AH P AA S T R AH F IY
APRIL EY P R AH L
AREA EH R IY AH
AUGUST AA G AH S T
B B IY
C S IY
CODE K OW D
D D IY
DECEMBER D IH S EH M B ER
E IY
EIGHT EY T
EIGHTEEN EY T IY N
EIGHTEENTH EY T IY N TH
EIGHT EY T TH
EIGHTY EY T IY
ELEVEN IH L EH V AH N
ELEVENTH IH L EH V AH N TH
ENTER EH N T ER
ERASE IH R EY S
F EH F
FEBRUARY F EH B Y AH W EH R IY
FIFTEEN F IH F T IY N
FIFTEENTH F IH F T IY N TH
FIFTH F IH F TH
FIFTY F IH F T IY
FIRST F ER S T
FIVE F AY V
FORTY F AO R T IY
FOUR F AO R
FOURTEEN F AO R T IY N
FOURTH F AO R TH
G JH IY
GO G OW
H EY CH
HALF HH AE F
HELP HH EH L P
HUNDRED HH AH N D R AH D
I AY
J JH EY
JANUARY JH AE N Y UW EH R IY
JULY JH UW L AY
JUNE JH UW N
K K EY
L EH L
M EH M
MARCH M AA R CH
MAY M EY
N EH N
NINE N AY N
NINETEEN N AY N T IY N
NINETY N AY N T IY
NINTH N AY N TH
NO N OW
NOVEMBER N OW V EH M B ER
O OW
OCTOBER AA K T OW B ER
OF AH V
OH OW
ONE W AH N
P P IY
Q K Y UW
R AA R
REPEAT R IH P IY T
RUBOUT R AH B AW T
S EH S
SECOND S EH K AH N D
SEPTEMBER S EH P T EH M B ER
SEVEN S EH V AH N
SEVENTEEN S EH V AH N T IY N
SEVENTH S EH V AH N TH
SEVENTY S EH V AH N T IY
SIX S IH K S
SIXTEEN S IH K S T IY N
SIXTEENTH S IH K S T IY N TH
SIXTH S IH K S TH
SIXTY S IH K S T IY
START S T AA R T
STOP S T AA P
T T IY
TEN T EH N
THIRD TH ER D
THIRTEEN TH ER T IY N
THIRTIETH TH ER T IY AH TH
THIRTY TH ER D IY
THOUSAND TH AW Z AH N D
THREE TH R IY
TWELFTH T W EH L F TH
TWELVE T W EH L V
TWENTIETH T W EH N T IY AH TH
TWENTY T W EH N T IY
TWO T UW
U Y UW
V V IY
W D AH B AH L Y UW
X EH K S
Y W AY
YES Y EH S
Z Z IY
ZERO Z IH R OW
```

Which generated the correct output being

```
AA
AE
AH
AO
AW
AY
B
CH
D
EH
ER
EY
F
G
HH
IH
IY
JH
K
L
M
N
<oov>
OW
P
R
S
T
TH
UW
V
W
Y
Z
```

The only difference between lexicon_a and lexicon_b is that word and phonemes are tab separated in lexicon_b and they are separated by a space in lexicon_a.

which is why I assumed that altering the delimiter in cut to be tab would be enough..

Comment: the messed up output is the actual output of snippet...

Comment: but it is not clear what is EXPECTED output... and typo in earlier comment: I meant `smaller sample`...

Comment: i changed it bit hopes it makes moe sense

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to take every string but the first column values on your lexicon.txt file and obtain just the unique strings from there, try:

```
cut -d' ' -f2- lexicon.txt | sed 's/^ *//g' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u
```

That is:

Remove the first column:

```
cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Delete trailing spaces at the beginning of lines:

```
 sed 's/^ *//g'
```

Change spaces into new lines in order to get the different strings in a single column:

```
tr ' ' '\n'
```

Unique sort the output:

```
sort -u
```

Comment: @bash What file did you try with? I see the outputs only in one column

Answer (score 0):

Using awk to extract the strings each on its own line and `sort | uniq` to weed out the duplicates.

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $i}' file | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & sort):

```
sed 's/^\S\S*\s*//;s/\s\s*/\n/g' file | sort -u
```

Remove the first field and its whitespace, then replace any furthur groups of on or more whitespace with newlines. Sort and remove duplicates.